# A result on absolute mean of a stopped supermartingale

Tags: pr.probability, martingales

The reason of posting the following problem here is that I heard that it is  a result from some paper.

Let $(X_n, \mathscr{F_n}), n \geq 0$ be a super martingale and $T$ an $\{F_n\}$-stopping time a.s. bounded by $N \lt \infty$. Show that

$$ E[|X_T|] \leq 3 \max_{n \leq N} E[|X_n|]$$

I can prove that   $$ E[|X_T|] \leq  E[\max_{n \leq N} |X_n|]$$. I am confused about how to get $3$ in the RHS.

Comment: Could you give a citation for the paper where you found this claim?

Comment: @NateEldredge: I have found that in a probability book by Borkar.

Comment: @malkhor Title? Chapter?